# Why is $\cos(-\pi) =-1?$

Tags: trigonometry

On the unit circle, I thought that $-\pi$ would be equivalent to $0$ or $2\pi$ similar to how $-\pi/2$ is actually $3\pi/2$ and $-3\pi/2$ is actually $\pi/2.$ In that case, $\cos(\pi)=-1,$ and $\cos(2\pi) = 1.$

So, why do we treat $\cos(-\pi)$ same as $\cos(\pi)?$

Comment: In general, $\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos x$ and $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x).$. Alternatively, $\cos(-x)=\cos(x).$

Comment: $-\pi$ is the same as $\pi$ on the unit circle. Go half a turn clockwise instead of counterclockwise.

Comment: Note that $-\frac\pi2$ is *equivalent* to $\frac{3\pi}2$ in the sense that $-\frac\pi2 = \frac{3\pi}2 + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$ (in fact $k=-1$). Similarly $-\frac{3\pi}2$ is equivalent to $\frac\pi2$ (since $-\frac{3\pi}2 = \frac\pi2 + 2\pi (-1)$). But there is no integer $k$ such that $-\pi=0+2\pi k$ nor $-\pi=2\pi+2\pi k$. Hence $-\pi$ is not equivalent to $0$ nor $2\pi$.

Comment: $-\pi/2$ is not “actually” $3\pi/2,$ but it is equivalent. If you rotate something $\pi/2$ clockwise, it gives the same result as rotating the thing $3\pi/2$ counterclockwise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, recall that cos$(\theta)$ represents the value of the $x$-coordinate and sin$(\theta)$ represents the value of the $y$-coordinate of the point on the circumference of a unit circle.

[image: Unit Circle]

Image sourced from:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:trig/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:unit-circle/a/trig-unit-circle-review

Trace the path of the point on the circumference of the circle as the value of $\theta$ changes. Notice when $\theta = \pi$, the point on the circle would have coordinates $(-1, 0)$, i.e. cos$(\pi) = -1$. If $\theta = -\pi$, the point would still have coordinates $(-1, 0)$ i.e. cos$(-\pi) = -1$. This is because rotating something $\pi$ counterclockwise is equivalent to rotating something $\pi$ clockwise, as mentioned by Cameron Williams in the comments.

Another way to think about it is to examine at the graph of cos$(\theta)$.

[image: Cosine Graph]

Image sourced from:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-sin-cos-tan-graphs.html

Notice how the cosine graph is symmetrical about the $y$-axis. Pay close attention to the values of cos$(\pi)$ and cos$(-\pi)$. They are both equal to $-1$.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Cameron Williams ' answer; what they mean is that basic circular functions ($\sin x$ or $\cos x$) always repeat on a period of $2\pi$. This means after $2\pi$ you will obtain the same output (See the unit circle below). Because there is no end (unless a domain is defined), one can express this in a **general form**:

Particularly, $\cos x$ for base of $\angle\pi$, takes on the general form,

$$\pi(2n + 1) \text{, } n \in \mathbb Z$$

This above form does not express **fully** for all angles of $\cos$.  Even though the value $-1$ only exists for $1$ angle per rotation ($2\pi$), other values like $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ have $2$ angles per rotation: in **Quadrant 1** $(\frac{\pi}{4})$ & **Quadrant 4** $(\frac{7\pi}{4})$. For more info see [Math is fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html) or [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)

[image: Unit Circle]